# Is a Pythonic MCVE acceptable for this top voted accepted GIS SE answer?

Tags: discussion, scope, code

I am in the process of writing my question requesting a clarification of this top voted accepted GIS SE answer - [Using Geohash for proximity searches](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/18330/using-geohash-for-proximity-searches/92331#92331) and I have a pythonic attempt as an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Is that on topic here because it also needs Cython to wrap the C library - [geohash-int](https://github.com/yinqiwen/geohash-int). There are several steps and I have taken care to illustrate in my MCVE which step points to which comment in the accepted answer. Is that on topic or will it be classified as "too broad" ?

My only concern is that the question maybe too long winded and whuber's concerns in this answer maybe popping up - [How much code is appropriate for an answer?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/445/how-much-code-is-appropriate-for-an-answer)

The question will provide a python script to illustrate the problem and the Cython wrapper of the C library. If the Cython wrapper is unnecessary and merely the python script is adequate then we can address the question as psuedo code(but with the Python script) without actually running it.

Comment: Stack Overflow points its MCVE link at https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example nowadays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Until you post your question it will be difficult to assess whether it is Too Broad for focused Q&A.

From https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example, as long as the code you present is minimal, complete and reproducible then you should be fine, as long as you only ask one question.

If you find yourself wanting to place more than one question mark, then chances are that you are asking more than one question, and drifting into Too Broad territory.